# Inserting a value in a column which has a NULL value

Tags: sql-server

I created a table in SQL Server and then decided to add another column using the `ALTER TABLE` statement. So I did this

```
ALTER TABLE Landlords
ADD NumberOfProperties numeric(10) NULL;
```

Now I'm unable to fill in a value in that row under the column `NumberOfProperties` as the first row has a `NULL` in it due to having data already in the other columns from the same row, how can I add a value in that `NULL` field ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update it: `UPDATE Landlords SET NumberOfProperties=@NumberOfProperties WHERE PK=@PK`

Answer (score 2):

```
update Landlords
   set NumberOfProperties = 42
where primaryKeyColumn = 1;
```